# In Wordpress dashboard, how to open link in new tab, in priority for pages/posts : open "Edit with Elementor" and "Edit" (with Wordpress) in new tab

Tags: dashboard

In the Wordpress dashboard, I would like to open some links in new tab instead of opening them in the same tab.

For example, and which is priority for me, in the case of a page/post : open "Edit with Elementor" or "Edit" (with Wordpress) in a new tab.

Could you help me to find the solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Those links would come from the Elementor plugin, so you'll need to ask them for help with this.

Comment: also middle clicking or cmd/ctrl+click also does this. Please edit your question down to specific links though, and ones that are not from 3rd party plugins, Elementor is offtopic here and not in this stacks scope